# Can we create a new site map for the SO301000 Sales Order like "Test Sales Order" site map in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

Do we have the feasibility to create the site map for Sales Order like **Test Sales Order** and when I click on this site map, I would like to load always one order details in the Test Sales Order screen.

If we have this feasibility, please provide me the solution.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at below screenshots.
1) This is how you can duplicate Sales Order screen

[image]

2) Create new TILE in Sales Menu and mention your order type and order #.

[image]